# os.execute command in ngx_lua_module gives sudo tty no ask no password?

Tags: unix, nginx, lua, tty, openresty

Hi I am configuring nginx.conf on my mac,,

I had to execute a lua script command like - os.execute(echo '' | sudo -S brew services restart nginx-full) which give password error, though I provided my actual mac user password. Also without the password as echo ,, In  my error.log, I see - sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

how do I get the permissions to do the os.execute the openresty command,, with content_lua_block. I also did the sudo visudo to add my user to set the NOPASS ALL, for permissions.

my /dev/tty has root user thats all ,, my username is sid,, how do i add sid to /dev/tty for permissions...??

Comment: What do you want to achieve? I can't think of any reason to run sudo from nginx. There should be another, more convenient way

Comment: Hi Alexey, I am trying to restart nginx,, using lua in nginx.conf. So that it refreshes my conf.d files. For this reason I am using os.execute command but it gives me permission denied , and asking password. Examples online are like this ps.execute("echo ' ' | /usr/local/etc/nginx/./restart") ,, where restart is sh file with sudo brew services restart nginx-full ,, also I tried this - os.execute("echo ' ' | sudo -S brew services restart nginx-full") still the same password and permission denied errors I have. Thxs.

Comment: Restarting nginx from inside nginx. Quite insane… Also, you don't need restart nginx to change config. Probably you should ask another question with the real problem you try try to fix

Comment: Ok Alexey,, thanks for replying, how do I do an auto refresh for my nginx so that it retains the $host url . My use case is this - the first time i enter microsoft.cloud.com , nginx creates a conf file for micorsoft and takes you to a html page, the second time after nginx refresh , it should now use the newly created microsoft conf file ,to proxy pass to microsoft website. Thanks again for your answers.

Comment: solved. sudo tty error resolved by providing root wheel as user on nginx.conf ,,